# Sinon stub not working in typescript with export class

Tags: typescript, sinon

for the unit test in mocha and Sinon in typescript, I get a test that fails on assertion. bar - is true Sinon stub but it was not called any time. Below is a link where tormozz48 user have asked I am facing the same issue in typescript.

https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/issues/1684

The problem here is it is unable to get an imported class method from another module so what I did is 
exported as

```
class Foo(){
}
export default new Foo()
```

and imported the same in another module like

```
import  * as foo  from 'foo.ts'
```

Now I can stub Sinon like above export. My question is that am I doing in the right way? Does exporting instance of the class is a better idea?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that works with no need to export the class:

```
    import * as chai from 'chai';

    import * as sinon from 'sinon';



    import { SomeClass } from './some.component';

    import { SinonStubbedInstance } from 'sinon';




    describe('SomeClass ', () => {

      beforeEach(() => {

        chai.should();

      });



      it('should create', () => {

        let classStub: SinonStubbedInstance<SomeClass>;

        classStub= sinon.createStubInstance(SomeClass);

        let expected: any = (classStub == undefined);

        expected.should.be.false;

      });

it('should call someMethod', () => {

    // Arrange

    let classStub: SinonStubbedInstance<SomeClass>;



    // Act

    classStub= sinon.createStubInstance(SomeClass);

    classStub.someMethod();



    // Assert

    classStub.someMethod.calledOnce.should.be.true;

  });
```

You can remove `chai` if you don't use it.

Comment: Hi please find detail question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61798668/sinon-in-typescript-stub
thanks